# Splitting up a submenu into columns, or putting existing menus in another menu as submenu item

Tags: menus

I have a menu with a long list of submenu items. I'd like to split that up into columns and the easiest way in my mind would be to have them split up into multiple . Is there a way to do this?

Alternatively, I've currently have the submenu items in four different menus (so that I can display them in four columns in the footer). Is it possible to put those menus in my main menu as submenu items?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Walker` class to customize your menus however you like.

A simple example of using `Walker` to create a custom menu can be found on the official WordPress Codex, here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker#General_Menu_Example

To do what you want using `Walker`, you would probably want to ensure that your menu has `X` parent items (where `X` is the number of columns you want), and each of your menu items is organized under one of those.

You would then use the `Walker::start_lvl()` and `Walker::end_lvl()` to output the container HTML for each of your columns, and `Walker::start_el()` to output each individual item.